# Why `list` in OCaml does not maintain a pointer to the last element?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

When we do `l1 @ l2`, it is `O(length(l1))` because we have to go through l1 and connect l1 and l2.

**So my question is that why the implementation does not maintain a `last_element` pointer?**

I ask this because I want to learn/understand the decision making process of `OCaml`'s standard library implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just going to the last element of `l1` would not help us. We need to copy the entire contents of `l1` and we can't do that without going through it. So having a pointer to the end of `l1` wouldn't help us.

Comment: you mean in order to keep immutable for l1 and l2?

Comment: @JacksonTale Right, if lists were mutable, we could just change the next pointer of `l1`'s last node to point to `l2`'s first node. But since they aren't, we need to copy `l1`.

Answer (score 5):

To build on sepp2k's answer:
List are implemented this way in OCaml.

```
type 'a list = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a list
```

a list l1 [1;2;3] can be thought in this way:

```
Cons (1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))
```

Say you want to concatenate it with l2, in Cons(3, Nil), you need to replace the Nil with l2, which is impossible since these elements are immutable. The new list is constructed this way:

```
Cons (1, Cons(2, Cons(3, l2)))
```

which is O(length(l1))

Answer (score 2):

Octref and sepp2k explained well why it's impossible to have `O(1)` appends with cons lists. I'd just like to point that you can always use other data structures that support constant time (amortized or worst case) appends.

Other options include:

1) Difference lists, have `O(1)` appends but need `O(n)` to turn them into cons lists. (Not aware of any implementations in OCaml however)

2) Catenable lists have `O(1)` amortized appends.

3) You can always use mutable linked lists. Such as `DllList` in batteries.